# How to populated data in JSON format slickgrid

Tags: json, slickgrid

I want to pass the data in slickgrid in JSON format, How do i do that. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform json to raw data, and pass it to instance of slickgrid. [Here](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/DataView#updating-data) is API how to update grid, so use it. Also look at the [Examples](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Examples%5C) - one of them are using AJAX and JSON.